# How to do Map<K, V> from Stream<Tuple2<K, V>> in java stream API?

Tags: java, dictionary, tuples, java-stream, collect

Oh. I have Java 8 and want to collect a

```
Map<K, V>
```

from

```
Stream<Tuple2<K, V>>
```

I do not want to use Pair, because of verbose syntax. Is there any way to do

```
.collect(toMap(Tuple2::_1, Tuple2::_2))
```

Thanx

Comment: What's the problem with `.collect(toMap(Tuple2::_1, Tuple2::_2))`? And what `Tuple2` class is that?

Comment: Oh... thanx man. Tuple2 is imported from vavr scala-like library. I'll do with pair.

Comment: @ernest_k I think the problem is that you can't access field values using the syntax for method references.

Comment: @flakes Maybe. Without knowing which `Tuple2` class that was, it was hard to tell whether `_1` or `_2` weren't methods...

Comment: @ernest_k ah nevermind, it looks like it is both a field and a method name!

Comment: Java 8 does not have `Tuple2` or `Pair` classes. What library is `Tuple2` coming from? What 'verbose syntax' are you referring to for `Pair` (again what library is `Pair` coming from)? What is the problem with the example you showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AFAIK**, This is not avoidable in java (*compared to the way its done in scala.*)

However If you're going to use a lot of Tuple to Map Conversions in your code and want to avoid verbose syntax, You could create a custom `TupleCollector` and add a `toMap` Method. 

This might be the closet you'll get to scala.

```
static class TupleCollector {
        public static <K, V, T extends Tuple2<K, V>> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, V>> toMap() {
            return Collectors.toMap(T::_1, T::_2);
        }
    }
```

Code to Invoke

```
import static TupleCollector.toMap
...
myStream.collect(toMap());
```

PS:
*Then again, I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't pass code review phase*.